# 'Auto-login' not working anymore

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using a firebase project for my app, on which users have to create an account to access to the content of the app.

In order to avoid users having to log in each time they launch the app, I put (in the AppDelegate) :

```
if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {
        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tabBar")
        self.window?.rootViewController = viewController
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    } else {
        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "InscriptionViewController")
        self.window?.rootViewController = viewController
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
```

And this piece of code did work for the past months but now it is not (all my pods are up to date)

Why is it not working anymore ?

Comment: Did you update all the firebase dependencies? And make sure you have a working internet connection.

Comment: My internet connection is working and I performed a pod update to make sure firebase was up to date. Do I have something more to do ?

Comment: Please check for google play services update as well. Also, if any kind of error is thrown then please post your logcat here.

Comment: I am sorry but I am a bit confused : why (and where / how) do I have to update google play services for an iOS app ? And no, no error is thrown

Answer (score 0):

Your AppDelegate should looks like this.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

  var window: UIWindow?

  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

  FirebaseApp.configure()

  if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {
  //your code 
  }

  }
}
```

Try to download google-info.plist
[image]

Comment: My code looks exactly like that and it was perfectly working before

Comment: Ok, try to download new google-info.plst from your https://console.firebase.google.com

Comment: One piece of information that could help : I changed my app bundle id. But the new bundle id corresponds to the one on firebase